# Can you embed an html view (e.g. google maps) from a SAP GUI screen?

Tags: google-maps, dynpro

Say for example we had an SAP Table with the Longitude and Latitude data. Can you use the google API to show the location in an embedded HTML view on SAP Screen WB03?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can use [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) to format and download image(s) with location markers, then compose HTML with downloaded images and show it anywhere, including an embedded HTML view.

Comment: Yes, but is this possible form the table view of SAP GUI?

Comment: Try add it as URL to external image.

Comment: Question updated. We need to extend the exiting WB03 SAP Screen with an HTML Viewer contain the google api. Is this possible?